Windows 10 install stuck at Windows logo
I have a PC with a Gigabyte GA-m68mt-s2 (Rev 3.1) motherboard and an AMD Sempron X2 190 CPU and 8 GB DDR3 and 256GB SSD.
I'm trying to install Windows 10.
I've downloaded the latest Windows 10 ISO and created the installation USB.
The motherboard supports only CSM, and it's the first time I tried to install Windows 10. The SSD is new.
I start the PC with USB, but the installation stops immediately after showing the Windows Logo.
Nothing happens after that. It's stuck there.
What can I do?

Has Windows 10 been installed before? Is there a license on the PC? Is BIOS set correctly? HAve you tried other OS, such as Linux?

Do you have CSM enabled or disable? Does the SSD have any partitions on it? If so is it MBR or GPT schema? Did you use the Media Creation Tool or some other tool to create the installation media? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

@Ramhound Edited the question.

You didn't answer all my questions.  Without the information I requested, in clear and specific detail, your question cannot be answered. I can almost guarantee the problem is a CSM/UEFI mismatch with the HDD schema (MBR/GPT) or the installation media itself is corrupt and you need to create it again.

It's impossible for a UEFI motherboard to "only support CSM". The sole purpose of CSM Mode was to support distros that didn't yet support EFI boot circa <2017 and should never be enabled unless needing to access a legacy OPROM; Windows has supported EFI boot since Win 7. To resolve, disable CSM Mode, enable Secure Boot, then boot the install USB. CSM Mode results in UEFI [64bit] emulating BIOS [16bit] in a 32bit environment and results in performance degradation - there is literally no use case for CSM Mode beyond legacy OPROMs.

(Cont'd...) The Gigabyte GA-m68mt-s2 appears to be BIOS not UEFI, so I'm unsure why CSM is even mentioned within the question body
